# sizeof operator & alignment in C++ vs D

Tags: c++, d, sizeof, memory-alignment

Consider following program:

```
#include <iostream>
class T {
  char c;
  int i;
};
int main() {
    std::cout<<sizeof(T)<<'\n';
}
```

It gives output `8` as an expected because of alignment. C++ Compiler adds padding of 3 bytes. But If I do the same in D language it gives me completely unexpected output. (See live demo [here](http://ideone.com/DjC7ot).)

```
import std.stdio;
class T {
  char c;
  int i;
}
int main() {
   writefln("sizeof T is %d",T.sizeof);
   writefln("sizeof char is %d",char.sizeof);
   writefln("sizeof int is %d",int.sizeof); 
   return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
sizeof T is 4
sizeof char is 1
sizeof int is 4
```

How `sizeof(T)` is 4 ? *I was expecting to get `8` as an output of class' size.* *How D compiler performs alignment here?* Am I understading wrong something ? I am using Windows 7 32 bit OS & Dmd compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Classes in D are reference types (i.e. they work like in Java or C#). When you declare a variable of type `T` (where `T` is a class), you're only declaring a class reference (which will be `null` by default), which will point to the actual class's data (the `char c` and `int i` in your example). Thus, `T.sizeof` only measures the size of the reference, which will be equal to the pointer size (a result of 4 only indicates that you're targeting a 32-bit platform).

Try declaring `T` as a `struct`:

```
import std.stdio;
struct T {
  char c;
  int i;
}
int main() {
   writefln("sizeof T is %d",T.sizeof);
   writefln("sizeof char is %d",char.sizeof);
   writefln("sizeof int is %d",int.sizeof); 
   return 0;
}
```

On my machine, the above outputs:

```
sizeof T is 8
sizeof char is 1
sizeof int is 4
```

Comment: so `sizeof` operator gives always 4 as an output because classes are reference type. Right ?

Comment: Yes, and to be more precise, `sizeof` always give 4 when targeting 32-bit architectures. When compiling for 64-bit, `sizeof` of a class reference will be 8.